# How to get Product rating code and its value in magento 2

Tags: blocks, magento2.2, product-page, ratings

I have modified **review** form as **popup** modal.And I have also created an **empty stars ratin**g for the product which does not contain rating yet.But I have created those **stars statically**. But Now I need to create those **stars dynamically** in **product page**. For that I need to get **rating code** and **value** in my phtml file. How Do I get rating code and value in my custom block file, **Now Need to get only the rating collection**

Block file

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YYY\Block;

class Render extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer
{

    protected $_availableTemplates = [
        self::FULL_VIEW => 'review.phtml',
        self::SHORT_VIEW => 'helper/summary_short.phtml',
    ];


    protected $_reviewFactory;
    protected $_ratingFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory, \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory, array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
        $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $reviewFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get review summary html
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $templateType
     * @param bool $displayIfNoReviews
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReviewsSummaryHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $templateType = self::DEFAULT_VIEW, $displayIfNoReviews = false
    )
    {

        if (!$product->getRatingSummary() && !$displayIfNoReviews) {
            return '';
        }
        // pick template among available

        if (empty($this->_availableTemplates[$templateType])) {

            $templateType = self::DEFAULT_VIEW;
        }

        $this->setTemplate($this->_availableTemplates[$templateType]);

        $this->setDisplayIfEmpty($displayIfNoReviews);

        if (!$product->getRatingSummary()) {
            $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $this->setProduct($product);

        return $this->toHtml();
    }
// I have written below code for rating collection but it retuns empty
    public function getRatings()
    {
echo"dhgdfh";
        return $this->_ratingFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->addEntityFilter(
                        'product'
                )->setPositionOrder()->addRatingPerStoreName(
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                )->setStoreFilter(
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                )->setActiveFilter(
                        true
                )->load()->addOptionToItems();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rating collection from below way,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

public function getRatingCollection(){
    $ratingCollection = $this->_ratingFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->addEntityFilter(
        'product' # TOFIX
    )->setPositionOrder()->setStoreFilter(
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->addRatingPerStoreName(
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->load();
    return $ratingCollection->getData();
}
```

call in phtml file with,

```
$block->getRatingCollection()
```