# How to get product rating collection in magento 2

Tags: collection, magento2.2, product-page, ratings

I need to get product rating collection in block, and need to display it in template.Please provide me a solution

Comment: please write in detail

Comment: Refer this link you will understand my issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206499/how-to-get-product-rating-code-and-its-value-in-magento-2 @ Ronak Chauhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Rating collection in magento as below way,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

public function getRatingCollection(){
    $ratingCollection = $this->_ratingFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->addEntityFilter(
        'product' # TOFIX
    )->setPositionOrder()->setStoreFilter(
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->addRatingPerStoreName(
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->load();
   echo "<pre>";print_r($ratingCollection->getData());
    return $ratingCollection->getData();
}
```

Above **`$ratingCollection->getData()`** function output will be like below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rating_id] => 4
            [entity_id] => 1
            [rating_code] => Rating
            [position] => 0
            [is_active] => 1
            [entity_code] => product
        )

)
```

Comment: How do I call only rating code and its value from this collection to my phtml code

Comment: you can call this function in your phtml i have added debug code you can check it.

Comment: If I have 3 ratings means, whether it can fetch that 3 rating codes

Comment: Yes 3 star means 3 ratings.